# Pdfjs-dist missing class properties transform

Tags: reactjs, pdf-viewer, pdfjs-dist

I'm trying to display a PDF file on a web page with the `@react-pdf-viewer/core` library.

My problem is that after installing this library and importing `import { Viewer, Worker } from '@react-pdf-viewer/core';` and use `<Worker/>`, the project doesn't compile, showing the following error:

```
./node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js
 SyntaxError: \node_modules\pdfjs-dist\build\pdf.js: Missing class properties transform.
 2925 |   #isEditing = false;
 2926 |   #isInEditMode = false;
 > 2927 |   _initialOptions = Object.create(null);
   |   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  2928 |   _uiManager = null;
  2929 |   _focusEventsAllowed = true;
  2930 |   #isDraggable = false;
```

I used this library in a raw project and it works correctly but I couldn't use it in my project.
I use these versions of the below items and I don't know exactly which information you need to help me.

```
"typescript": "^4.7.4",
"react-scripts": "3.2.0",
```

My problem is similar to the below link but I can't downgrade the version of `pdfjs-dist`
[Similar Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74585010/react-pdf-missing-class-properties-transform)